# In Orbot, obfs3 bridges don't work.

Tags: bridge, orbot

I have Orbot 14.0.5 installed from F-droid.
obfs3 bridge lines are ignored by Orbot and orbot just connects directly to tor network. 
For pasting bridge lines in Orbot, Should I add the word "Bridge" before "obfs3 IP:PORT hash" or should I just use "obfs3 IP:PORT hash" in 1 line?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [code](https://gitweb.torproject.org/orbot.git/blob/HEAD:/src/org/torproject/android/service/TorService.java#l1957), using `obfs3 IP:PORT HASH` is the right form.

The debug log should contain bridge lines that are added.